# java jackson databinding for a HashMap<String,LinkedList<Investor>>

Tags: java, json, serialization, data-binding, jackson

I'm trying to load a value taken from a JSON file.
The target object where -reloading the JSON file is:

`HashMap<String,LinkedList<Investor>> investors_per_location=new HashMap<>();`

What I'm doing is creating a couple of Types:

```
                MapType mapType = null;
                CollectionType mapTypeAux = null;
                mapTypeAux = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(LinkedList.class,Investor.class);                  
                mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class,mapTypeAux.getClass());
                investors_per_location=objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, mapType);
```

My best guess is that, this is not the way to include a linkedlist within a hashmap to load it back from a JSON file.
Any clue?
Thx in advance, David.

Comment: Solved:
I added next prefix as part of the sparql query and now it works within Jena:     

PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `TypeReference` instead:

```java
TypeReference<Map<String, LinkedList<Investor>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, LinkedList<Investor>>>(){};
Map<String, LinkedList<Investor>> investorsPerLocation = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, typeRef);
```

Comment: Thx. Now I get to fight next deserialization problem.